# Client doesn't revieve response in nested callbacks

Tags: ros-humble, services, callbacks, action-server, multithreading

I want to create node which provides a action server, this server expects the name of a waypoint and is then able to ask other nodes which calculate the pose of the waypoint for the appropriate `MotionPlanRequest` before filling in the last bits and providing it to MoveIts `move_group` for planning and execution.

Within the service `goal_handle` I formulate and send the service request for one of the "waypoint calculation" nodes. I see that the respective node is receiving and responding to the request, but within my node the request is never received. The future status `std::future_status status = this->waypoint_response_.wait_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));` will return time-out every time. The handle for action request accepted creates a thread and detaches it, like in the [example](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Intermediate/Writing-an-Action-Server-Client/Cpp.html).

What am I doing wrong?

Code snipped constructing service clients for waypoint retrival:

```
auto getWaypoint_callbackgroup = this->create_callback_group(rclcpp::CallbackGroupType::Reentrant);

    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "Registering service get_waypoint services:" << std::endl;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < waypointNames.size(); i++)
    {
        ss << "  " << waypointServiceNames[i] << std::endl;
        rclcpp::Client<GetWaypointService>::SharedPtr waypointService =
            this->create_client<GetWaypointService>(waypointServiceNames[i],
                                                    rmw_qos_profile_services_default,
                                                    getWaypoint_callbackgroup);
        this->getWaypoint_s_map_.insert(
            std::pair<std::string, rclcpp::Client<GetWaypointService>::SharedPtr>(waypointNames[i],
                                                                                  waypointService));
    }
    RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), ss.str().c_str());
```

Code snipped using the service clients:

```
rclcpp_action::GoalResponse
MotionManager::moveTo_goalhandle(const rclcpp_action::GoalUUID &uuid,
                                 std::shared_ptr<const MoveToAction::Goal> moveTo_goal)
{
    (void)uuid;

    RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(),
                "MoveTo request recieved for waypoint '%s'.",
                moveTo_goal->waypoint_name.c_str());

    rclcpp::Client<GetWaypointService>::SharedPtr waypointService = nullptr;
    auto waypointRequest = std::make_shared<GetWaypointService::Request>();
    waypointRequest->waypoint_name = moveTo_goal->waypoint_name;

    if (moveTo_goal->predefined)
    {
        RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Using predefined waypoints.");

        waypointService = this->getWaypoint_s_map_["predefined"];
    }
    else
    {
        waypointService = this->getWaypoint_s_map_[moveTo_goal->waypoint_name];
    }

    while (!waypointService->wait_for_service(std::chrono::seconds(1)))
    {
        if (!rclcpp::ok())
        {
            RCLCPP_ERROR(this->get_logger(), "Interrupted while waiting for the service. Exiting.");
            return rclcpp_action::GoalResponse::REJECT;
        }
        RCLCPP_WARN(this->get_logger(), "Wait for service");
    }

    RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Waypoint '%s' requested.", moveTo_goal->waypoint_name.c_str());
    this->waypoint_response_ = waypointService->async_send_request(waypointRequest).future.share();

    return rclcpp_action::GoalResponse::ACCEPT_AND_EXECUTE;
}
```

Code snipped retrieving the date from the response:

```
std::future_status status = this->waypoint_response_.wait_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));

    std::stringstream statusWaypoint_ss;
    statusWaypoint_ss << "Waypoint response for '" << waypoint_name << "': ";
    if (this->waypoint_response_.valid())
    {

        switch (status)
        {
        case std::future_status::deferred:
            statusWaypoint_ss << "Deferred";
            RCLCPP_WARN(this->get_logger(), statusWaypoint_ss.str().c_str());
            feedback->status_msg = statusWaypoint_ss.str().c_str();
            feedback->rcl_code = 6;
            result->success = false;
            moveTo_goalhandle->succeed(result);
            return;
        case std::future_status::timeout:
            statusWaypoint_ss << "Timeout";
            RCLCPP_WARN(this->get_logger(), statusWaypoint_ss.str().c_str());
            feedback->status_msg = statusWaypoint_ss.str().c_str();
            feedback->rcl_code = 6;
            result->success = false;
            moveTo_goalhandle->succeed(result);
            return;
        case std::future_status::ready:
            statusWaypoint_ss << "Ready";
            RCLCPP_DEBUG(this->get_logger(), statusWaypoint_ss.str().c_str());
            feedback->status_msg = statusWaypoint_ss.str().c_str();
            feedback->rcl_code = 4;

            auto currentMotionPlanRequest = std::make_shared<MotionPlanRequest>(this->waypoint_response_.get()->waypoint);
```